# NanoHTTPD.javaでIP制限を行いたい

Tags: android, java, nanohttpd

minSdkVersion : 19
targetSdkVersion: 19

http://komamitsu.hatenablog.com/entry/20120223/1330013934
上記を参考にAndroid上でNanoHTTPDを動かしています。

アクセス元の制限(IP制限)により配信可否を行いたいと思っています。

[AndroidWebServerActivity.java](https://gist.github.com/komamitsu/1893396#file-androidwebserveractivity-java)の

```
@Override
public Response serve(String uri, String method,
        Properties header, Properties parms, Properties files) {

    final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (Entry<Object, Object> kv : header.entrySet())
        buf.append(kv.getKey() + " : " + kv.getValue() + "\n");

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hello.setText(buf);
        }
    });

    final String html = "<html><head><head><body><h1>Hello, World</h1></body></html>";
    return new NanoHTTPD.Response(HTTP_OK, MIME_HTML, html);
}
```

の中で、パラメータの中にリクエスト元のIPアドレスがないか確認しましたが、uri,method,header,parms,filesに全てにリクエスト元IPアドレスの情報はありませんでした。

アクセス元の制限をかけるにはどのようにすればいいかご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

JavaSE環境で見た限りでは `session.getHeaders().get("remote-addr")` で取得できています。

https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/0f5ae0751dcaf3182ba094403debaf085b3ac58e/core/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/NanoHTTPD.java#L819-L820

Comment: NanoHTTPDでの使い方がわかっておりません。こちら（後にURLを掲載)も参考にしましたが、public Response serve(final IHTTPSession session) {}のメソッドがNanoHTTPDに無い模様です。 https://github.com/DeviceConnect/DeviceConnect-Android/blob/master/dConnectDevicePlugin/dConnectDeviceChromeCast/src/org/deviceconnect/android/deviceplugin/chromecast/core/ChromeCastHttpServer.java

Answer (score 1):

参考サイトで Override している serve メソッドは、NanoHTTPD [v1.1](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/nanohttpd-for-java1.1/NanoHTTPD.java) のものであり、[v1.6](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/NanoHTTPD.java) の serve メソッドとは互換性がありません。

1.1 では`remote-addr`情報は Header に含められていません。一方 1.6 では、`remote-addr`と`http-client-ip`が Header に含められています。

なので、アクセス制御のためには、v1.6 を使って実現するように持って行くしかないでしょう。

1.6 には、参考サイトの

```
public Response serve(String uri, String method,
    Properties header, Properties parms, Properties files)
```

はなくなり（実際は非推奨化）、代わりに

```
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session)
```

となっています。ということで、**yukihane さん回答済の`sesstion.getHeaders().get("remote-addr")`を使う場合** 、`serve`メソッドを Override して、その中で、`session`オブジェクトを利用して、リモードアドレスをチェックする処理を入れてから、親クラスの処理に渡すという形にするのがいいと思います。

```
private static final CharSequence FORBIDDEN = "192.168.0.3";

@Override
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {

    String remoteAddr = session.getHeaders().get("remote-addr");
    if (remoteAddr.contains(FORBIDDEN)) {
        return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.HTTP_FORBIDDEN,
            NanoHTTPD.MIME_HTML, "<p>Your are not allowed to access.</p>");
    }

    super.serve(session);
}
```

Comment: こちらのhost情報は取得先の<ホスト名>:<ポート番号>ではないのでしょうか？

Comment: @Ubunkun 勘違いしていました、HTTP Header の Host は remote_host ではなかったですね。参考サイトの内容は NanoHTTPD の v1.1 がベースになっていますが、1.1 では remote_addr を取得する機能はありません。一方、yukihaneさんの情報は、1.6 のものです。v1.6 を使って、参考サイトと同様のことを実現するような形に持っていかないと、remote_addr によるアクセス制御はできないと思います。

Comment: v1.6に変更しました。String remoteAddr = session.getHeaders.get("remote-addr");の部分で、「getHeaders は解決できないか、フィールドではありません」のエラーが発生します。使っている物が異なるのでしょうか？

Comment: getHeaders() でした。カッコが必要でした。本文の方も訂正しておきました。

Answer (score 1):

[getRemoteSocketAddress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getRemoteSocketAddress%28%29) を使うのはどうでしょうか。

クライアントからアクセスがあると(`HTTPSession(myServerSocket.accept());`)、スレッドが生成されて `HTTPSession` クラスのインスタンスが作成されます。そのコンストラクタ内でアドレスのフィルタリングを行うことになるかと思います。

```
/**
 * Starts a HTTP server to given port.<p>
 * Throws an IOException if the socket is already in use
 */
public NanoHTTPD( int port, File wwwroot ) throws IOException
{
  myTcpPort = port;
  this.myRootDir = wwwroot;
  myServerSocket = new ServerSocket( myTcpPort );
  myThread = new Thread( new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        try
        {
          while( true )
            new HTTPSession( myServerSocket.accept());
            //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }
        catch ( IOException ioe )

               :

/**
 * Handles one session, i.e. parses the HTTP request
 * and returns the response.
 */
private class HTTPSession implements Runnable
{
  public HTTPSession( Socket s )
  {
    mySocket = s;

    // Here  
    SocketAddress remoteIPAddress = mySocket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
    System.out.println(remoteIPAddress);
    // => /192.168.0.3:49825

    Thread t = new Thread( this );
    t.setDaemon( true );
    t.start();
  }
```